# how to debug jQuery ajax url working or not with CodeIgniter

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am using jquery ajax with codeigniter but ajax url not working

In Codeigniter view page,

```
$.ajax( {
    type: 'POST',
        url: "<?php echo base_url()?>Controller_name/function_name",
        data: {aaa:value1},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( data ) {
        alert( data );
    }
});
```

**In CI Controller**

```
<?php
    class Controller_name extends CI_Controller {
        public function function_name() {
            echo 'Hello World!';
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is check whether request has been sent properly or not.

1. open your browser and go to developer console (chrome right click
   and inspect)
2. switch to network tab
3. send your request and monitor the network tab
4. confirm your request status code is 200
5. otherwise get the error message to debug the program

if status code is 200,

1. click on the request file in the network tab and you will see response tab next
2. check response is available inside the response tab

   [image]

Comment: i tried above steps in browser response  code check ajax url correct show path but its not go to controller what happens here

Comment: if request code is 200 and response is not available it`s something wrong in your controller.i guess you need to return value from controller rather than echo out

Comment: which means your request is fine.can you see response in response tab? if it is empty something wrong in controller. try to encode data to json and send like this `echo json_encode($data);`

Answer (score 0):

`dataType: 'JSON'` is used to convert response to JS Objects.

Looks like you haven't received any JSON String:

```
echo 'Hello World!';
```

Therefore, the jQuery is producing JSON Syntex Error.

Try to remove `dataType:'JSON'`